# Magento Subdomain Error

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have a Magento installed on a subdomain. (say http://subdomain.domain.com)

My problem is when I am using http://subdomain.domain.com/admin, it works.

But when I am trying to access http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/admin, it is throwing following error:

"No input file specified."

This works on my main domain, i.e.

http://domain.com/admin and http://domain.com/index.php/admin both work on main domain.

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

What changes should I make in my main .htaccess or subdomain's .htaccess to make my magento admin work properly.

Comment: Its a dedicated server, in which we configured such that main domain takes all folders as sub-domain.

Comment: Where is your htaccess codes for your domains?